# Integrating MEAN Stack App using angular 2 / 4 with Keystone CMS

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack, keystonejs

I have an existing MEAN stack app, Where i want to add a CMS, basically using the app as a blogging site. So looking for the features that wordpress offers for blogging.

I am using angular-cli for scaffolding of angular 2 app.

took a few clues from [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/wiki/How-to-Add-Keystone-to-an-Already-Existing-Express-App), but it was not that much helpful. Please if anyone can give some clue, TIA.

Comment: Did you get to know how to use keystone with existing mean stack app. I am using mongodb native driver and not mongoose, since I didnt want to stick with schema based database design . Will keystone work with mongodb without mongoose?